# Gitolite hook doesn't work

Tags: windows, git, cygwin, gitolite

I've set **a GIT server on Windows** with *Cygwin* and *gitolite* as it's described in [the article](http://therightstuff.de/2010/03/28/How-To-Set-Up-A-Git-Server-On-Windows-Using-Cygwin-And-Gitolite.aspx).
On a client Windows machine I use *TortoiseGit*.

Right after the setup everything works ok. I can clone *gitolite-admin* repository with *TortoiseGit* using my SSH key and see the repository content.

But right after I try to push a new content of */conf/gitolite.conf* the server is not accessible anymore using my SSH key (it's removed from *authorised_keys* on the server by gitolite).

The new content of gitolite.conf (I would like to add new repository *Project*):

```
repo    gitolite-admin
        RW+     =   alexey

repo    Project
        RW+     =   alexey

repo    testing
        RW+     =   @all
```

**What's wrong with it?**

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in **sshd service** environment. See [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/gitolite/browse_thread/thread/8744adf8253feb73) for details.

To fix the problem reinstall the service with proper PATH variable setting. To do this on Windows Server 2008 use:

```
cygrunsrv -R sshd
cygrunsrv -I sshd -d "CYGWIN sshd" -p /usr/sbin/sshd -a "-D" -y tcpip -u cyg_server -w {cyg_server_password} --env "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem"
cygrunsrv -S sshd
```

If you don't remember cyg_server account password you can rerun *ssh-host-config*.

To restore access for your public key use:

```
gl-setup ~/YourKey.pub
```

After these you can access and modify your *gitolite-admin* repository remotely.

Comment: thanks, this fixed `/usr/bin/find: paths must precede expression` errors