# gitolite can't add keys to authorized_keys when pushing

Tags: cygwin, gitolite

cloning gitolite-admin to my workstation and managing users and repo, but when pushing, I got some errors like this:

```
remote: Initialized empty Git repository in /home/git/repositories/fmame.git/
remote: /bin/find: paths must precede expression
remote: Usage: /bin/find [path...] [expression]
remote: /bin/find: paths must precede expression
remote: Usage: /bin/find [path...] [expression]
remote: /bin/find: paths must precede expression
remote: Usage: /bin/find [path...] [expression]
remote: /bin/find: paths must precede expression
remote: Usage: /bin/find [path...] [expression]
remote: /bin/find: paths must precede expression
remote: Usage: /bin/find [path...] [expression]

To git@localhost:gitolite-admin
```

here is my steps:

1/ editing gitolite.conf：

```
repo gitolite-admin
    RW+     =   gitoliteadm

repo testing
    RW+     =   @all

repo mfame
    RW+ = ryoma
```

2/ puts `ryoma.pub` in `keydir` directory.

and I have my work running on windows 7 within cygwin.

How would you modify this setup in order to allow me cloning the gitolite-admin repo?

Answer (score 0):

Following "[Gitolite hook doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9401080/6309)", make sure your sshd (ssh daemon running on your gitolite server) has a proper `PATH`.

That (improper `PATH`) could causes the "`remote: /bin/find: paths must precede expression`" error message, because in might select the wrong shell.